# PDF of a discontinuous CDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a probleme with a discontinuous CDF where i want to find the PDF. 
The CDF is
\begin{equation}
F(x) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & x < 0 \\
      x\frac{1}{4} & 0\leq x < 1 \\
      \frac{1}{2} + x\frac{1}{4} & 1 \leq x < 2  \\
      1 & 2 \leq x
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}

So there is a jump of height $\frac{1}{2}$ at $x=1$ and the slope at the left and right hand side of $x=1$ is equal to $\frac{1}{4}$.

I think the PDF has a mass of height $\frac{1}{2}$ at $x=1$ additional to

\begin{equation}
p(x) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & x < 0 \\
      \frac{1}{4} & 0\leq x < 2 \\
      0 & 2 \leq x \;.
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Is that right? If yes, how can I write that PDF as one function and how would you plot that PDF? And what value does the PDF obtains at $x=1$? Is it $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}$ or $\frac{3}{4}$? It very much confuses me.

Thank you very much

Comment: If you meant PDF w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure, then it doesn't exists, as the CDF needs to be absolutely continuous. However you can decompose your probability measure into a sum of an absolutely continuous measure and a singular measure. The first one has a PDF w.r.t. The Lebesgue measure, the second has a PDF w.r.t. a counting measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, there is a mass of $\frac 1 2$ at $x = 1$.

For your question on how to write such a PDF and what value it has at $x = 1$, here are two hints that might help you:
1) You can add a dirac delta function to your PDF.
2) The PDF must integrate to 1.

Comment: thanks very much for the two hints. I got it. yiihaa :)

Comment: I note that the p(x) function provided in the question cannot be correct since for this function p(x<=1)=1/4 (regardless of the mass at 1) while according to given cumulative function p(x<=1)=3/4. How does adding the Dirac function change this?